# There is some missing things in chart

Tags: r, charts, quantmod

I made following function for convenient usage for myself, but line "MeanData60" never goes out on result chart.

```
ShowStock <- function(Name)
{
    Data <- getSymbols(Name, auto.assign=FALSE);

    chartSeries(  Data, name=Name, subset="last 1 year", TA=c(addMACD())  )

    MeanData20 <- runMean(Data[,4], n=20)
    addTA(MeanData20, on=1, col="brown1")
    MeanData60 <- runMean(Data[,4], n=60)
    addTA(MeanData60, on=1, col="cadetblue1")
}

ShowStock("YHOO")
```

I don't get it.
Please help to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.  Perhaps restart your graphics device (or just restart R).  All addTA lines are on the plot.

Comment: Thanks for reply.

Following descriptions are found with command "?TA", my code finally works well after apply it.

    Calling any of the above methods from within a function or script will generally require them to be wrapped in a plot call as they rely on the context of the call to initiate the actual charting addition.